# How did Google manage to do this? Slide ActionBar in Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-actionbar, android-side-navigation

I really want to implement this (the side navigation) in an app of my own, does anyone know how Google managed to do this?

They seem to have pulled the current window aside and put in a fly-in navigation of their own.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that they just have a layout that contains 2 layouts: 1 is the main app, and the other is the sidebar. When the sidebar is activated, it pushes the main app layout aside. This is just a guess though, so I didn't put it as an answer.

Comment: I believe someone asked this at the Q&A after the "What's new in Android" talk at IO. The recorded version isn't available yet, and I unfortunately do not remember what the answer was.

Comment: @Tanis.7x The answer was pretty much that they don't plan a framework component for this menu yet, but that you can find a good series of blog posts [over here](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658) *(as far as I remember)*.

Comment: Sounds right to me, and thanks for the link!

Comment: I read that blog post. They say they implemented a custom actionbar. Now this sounds reasonable by a developer but not by Google that is hacking its own api!

Comment: But that's expected in an open system that is always encouraging people to invent new and good ways for user interaction (in this case, the innovation is in the Android app, as this is an ancient-old idea).

Comment: The answers to this question are now "quazi" out of date. Google has now introduce the Navigation Drawer, and the approach will be different than that of the ones currently listed.

Comment: Link to the Navigation Drawer: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In fact, there's a way to do this. Even without implementing your own `ActionBar`.

Just have a look at the `hierachyviewer`! (Located in the tools directory)

There's the `DecorView`, and a `LinearLayout` as a child. This `LinearLayout` contains both the `ActionBar` and the other content. So, you can simply apply some `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` to this `LinearLayout` and get some space on the left side this way. Then, you can fill this space with your menu-ListView and overlay the other content with a FrameLayout, that, when it's clicked, collapses the menu. So, here's some code:

First, the class for collapsing / expanding (SlideMenu.java):

```
package your.cool.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlideMenu {
//just a simple adapter
public static class SlideMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SlideMenu.SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc> {
    Activity act;
    SlideMenu.SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] items;
    class MenuItem {
        public TextView label;
        public ImageView icon;
    }
    static class MenuDesc {
        public int icon;
        public String label;
    }
    public SlideMenuAdapter(Activity act, SlideMenu.SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] items) {
        super(act, R.id.menu_label, items);
        this.act = act;
        this.items = items;
        }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_listitem, null);
            MenuItem viewHolder = new MenuItem();
            viewHolder.label = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_label);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        MenuItem holder = (MenuItem) rowView.getTag();
        String s = items[position].label;
        holder.label.setText(s);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(items[position].icon);

        return rowView;
    }
}

private static boolean menuShown = false;
private static View menu;
private static LinearLayout content;
private static FrameLayout parent;
private static int menuSize;
private static int statusHeight = 0;
private Activity act;
SlideMenu(Activity act) {
    this.act = act;
}
//call this in your onCreate() for screen rotation
public void checkEnabled() {
    if(menuShown)
        this.show(false);
}
public void show() {
//get the height of the status bar
    if(statusHeight == 0) {
        Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        Window window = act.getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
        statusHeight = rectgle.top;
        }
    this.show(true);
}
public void show(boolean animate) {
    menuSize = Functions.dpToPx(250, act);
    content = ((LinearLayout) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) content.getLayoutParams();
    parm.setMargins(menuSize, 0, -menuSize, 0);
    content.setLayoutParams(parm);
//animation for smooth slide-out
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(-menuSize, 0, 0, 0);
    ta.setDuration(500);
    if(animate)
        content.startAnimation(ta);
    parent = (FrameLayout) content.getParent();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lays = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1, 3);
    lays.setMargins(0,statusHeight, 0, 0);
    menu.setLayoutParams(lays);
    parent.addView(menu);
    ListView list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //handle your menu-click
        }
    });
    if(animate)
        menu.startAnimation(ta);
    menu.findViewById(R.id.overlay).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SlideMenu.this.hide();
        }
    });
    Functions.enableDisableViewGroup((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent(), false);
    ((ExtendedViewPager) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)).setPagingEnabled(false);
    ((ExtendedPagerTabStrip) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_tabs)).setNavEnabled(false);
    menuShown = true;
    this.fill();
}
public void fill() {
    ListView list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
    SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] items = new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[5];
    //fill the menu-items here
    SlideMenuAdapter adap = new SlideMenuAdapter(act, items);
    list.setAdapter(adap);
}
public void hide() {
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, -menuSize, 0, 0);
    ta.setDuration(500);
    menu.startAnimation(ta);
    parent.removeView(menu);

    TranslateAnimation tra = new TranslateAnimation(menuSize, 0, 0, 0);
    tra.setDuration(500);
    content.startAnimation(tra);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) content.getLayoutParams();
    parm.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content.setLayoutParams(parm);
    Functions.enableDisableViewGroup((LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent(), true);
    ((ExtendedViewPager) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)).setPagingEnabled(true);
    ((ExtendedPagerTabStrip) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_tabs)).setNavEnabled(true);
    menuShown = false;
}
}
```

Some helping methods (for me, in static Functions.java):

```
    public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context ctx) {
    Resources r = ctx.getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
//originally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views
//modified for the needs here
public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if(view.isFocusable())
            view.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
            } else if (view instanceof ListView) {
                if(view.isFocusable())
                    view.setEnabled(enabled);
                ListView listView = (ListView) view;
                int listChildCount = listView.getChildCount();
                for (int j = 0; j < listChildCount; j++) {
                    if(view.isFocusable())
                        listView.getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Then, the layouts:

Layout of the menu (res/layout/menu.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:background="@color/darkblack">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/dividerblack"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip"  />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout of the listitems (res/layout/menu_listitem.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to use it:

In your `onCreate()`:

```
private SlideMenu slidemenu;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //your onCreate code
    slidemenu = new SlideMenu(this);
    slidemenu.checkEnabled();
}
```

In the handler for your ActionBar homebutton:

```
slidemenu.show();
```

That's it!

And now, a little screenshot of it in action:

[image: SlideMenu]

As far as I know, it is working. If you experience any problems or my explanations are not clear, please contact me!

EDIT: `ExtendedViewPager` & `ExtendedPagerStrip`:

ExtendedViewPager:

```
package your.cool.app;

//source: http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ExtendedViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean enabled;

public ExtendedViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
}
```

ExtendedPagerTabStrip:

```
package your.cool.app;

//source: http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ExtendedPagerTabStrip extends PagerTabStrip {

private boolean enabled;

public ExtendedPagerTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setNavEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
}
```

I use this `SlideMenu` for an Activity with a `ViewPager` with `PagerTabStrip` for tabs like Talk, Market etc. You can't disable these Views in an easy way, so the two classes above just extend them to stop the `onTouch` event when disabled.

Comment: Looks great, but where do ExtendedViewPager and ExtendedPagerTabStrip come from?

Comment: Cool, thanks for the extra files, I'll try to convert that to a lib and post on github.

Comment: I am guessing you must put a extendedViewPager and extendedPagerTabStrip in the XML for your activity, right?  The example above looks for R.id.viewpager

Comment: @hwrdprkns Has anyone tried this with ActionBarSherlock on a gingerbread device?  I am getting some weird behavior....

Comment: @Patrick if you don't have a viewpager, just leave out these two lines. If you have misc with viewpager / no viewpager, put these lines in between a try / catch block.
I don't know what ActionBarSherlock does, you need to take a look at hierachyviewer, because this is just a hack, and if ActionBarSherlock tries to hack the same way, there could be a mess.

Comment: @Patrick: @Scirocco is correct. Take a look with `hierarchyviewer` to see what ActionBarSherlock is really doing behind the scenes. Then you can manipulate the views accordingly.

Comment: So I'm looking to get the same setup using ActionbarSherlock, and looking at the hierarchy view isn't helping me. What should I be looking for? I'm not overly familiar with the tool, nor how the hierarchy view works :/ . I have the view, and it slides properly, it just takes up the whole screen rather than leaving a sliver with the app icon showing.

Comment: Hi, we did a roundup of sciroccos original implementation and added XML parsing as well as autodetection of a possibly present actionbar. The whole thing is now a library project togther with an example app and is described over at http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/07/tech-stuff-a-sliding-menu-for-android-very-much-like-the-google-and-facebook-apps-have-it/. Thanks   to @Scirocco for the initial idea!

Comment: Should I post a separate question for how we should modify this code to have the slidemenu slide out from the right side?  I would like one  for each side of the app.

Comment: I implemented the method and it works on android 4.1 , but in android 2.3 doesn't? is it build just for higher versions of android?

Comment: @Fred : That would be great! If you could do that I'd favorite it when it gets answered!

Comment: @Scirocco i am using your code for menu options, here i am facing problem, what is the Functions class. what code i have to add into that and also how to use the above code in the main activity. please help on this i did not figured out how to create...

Comment: @RajaReddyP The Functions class contains some helping methods of my app. You find the extract you need for the slidemenu to work above, it's the second code block

Comment: @Patrick, for device with android < 4.0, just add parm.gravity = Gravity.Top before  parm.setMargins(menuSize, 0, -menuSize, 0), and set the statusHeight to 0.

Comment: Nice job! I would like to add sub menu items (for example check facebook app). So when selecting a menu item with a sub item, the menu needs to animate to the right. Any tips for implementing this?

Comment: @Scirocco can you grant use of the above code under the MIT or BSD license?  Thanks!

Comment: @JamesBaca personally, I don't like the idea of my code being used in closed-source projects without mentioning me. This code is available under both this stackoverflow-CC-by-SA kind of thing and the GPL (http://github.com/LSGAdmins/lsgapp). I hope that's enough!

Comment: Very nice code, I've been tinkering with it, and when you have the comment //fill the menu-items here in the fill() method in SlideMenu, I keep getting nullpointerexceptions. What would be the proper way to instantiate a menu item?

Comment: @Scirocco Hey ! i have question of what does this line meant for bcoz i didnt find any id in your code 
((ExtendedViewPager) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)).setPagingEnabled(false);
    ((ExtendedPagerTabStrip) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_tabs)).setNavEnabled(false);

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Do you have any suggestion? I appreciated all your work and it is very helpful for me. I'm just getting started with Android. My problem is I don't know how my Activity should be to make it work.

Comment: Hi ! we have the same question as "raghav chopra" regarding these lines ((ExtendedViewPager) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)).setPagingEnabled(false); ((ExtendedPagerTabStrip) act.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_tabs)).setNavEnabled(false);  where is the layout regarding to them could help me with that.

Answer (score 21):

There are several *attempts* at doing this, however I have yet to find a lib or source code on how to implement it successfully with actionbar accross all api levels.  One promising lib is here

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

here is a video of the [example app](http://youtu.be/8vNaANLHw-c).

here is the [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example) app link.

This does work with ActionbarSherlock.  You will have to build the SlidingMenu library with ABS to get it working.  Works and looks great!

Comment: While the code above will generally work, I can say without a doubt that this library is a great drop-in solution to this problem. It's really started to grow on me as a ready-made solution for implementing a side-nav.

Comment: Agree that this library has been really helpful for us - super easy to use, provides many config options, works on many API levels, and plays nice with ActionBarSherlock!

Answer (score 8):

Did a roundup of the [original implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367825/361413) and added XML parsing as well as `autodetection` of a possibly present `actionbar`, so it works with the native as well as a support action bar such as `ActionBarSherlock`.

The whole thing is now a library project together with an example app and is described over at [Sliding Menu for android](http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/07/tech-stuff-a-sliding-menu-for-android-very-much-like-the-google-and-facebook-apps-have-it/) Thanks to [**scirocco**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150188/scirocco/) for the initial idea and code!

[image: LibSlideMenu Screenshot]

Comment: I need to set slide menu as the first screen.that is when the user enter into the app he will see the slide menu first .is any solution for that ?

Comment: setAsShown() added with https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu/commit/990edce77cf08881ad4a2b6d27a9f1354aadbc25 should do the trick.

Comment: Nice job! I would like to add sub menu items (for example check facebook app). So when selecting a menu item with a sub item, the menu needs to animate to the right. Any tips for implementing this?

Comment: @Luizje: I guess you would have to use a similar view like the SlideMenu, but smaller and use an animation on that. I'd be happy to merge in any patches you might have :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using API level greater that 11 you can use a much simpler approach inspired by the [answer given by @Scirocco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367825/356895)

```
// get content parent that is basically the whole 
// app screen (viewed from hierarchy viewer)
final LinearLayout content = 
     (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();

// make new value animator with range from 0 to 1
final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
// set custom duration
animator.setDuration(500);
// on update is called for every value in the 
    // given range in time frame defined by the duration
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        // get the current value
        float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();
        // translate by that value, minus means translate left
        content.setTranslationX(-250 * value);
    }
});
// start the animator
animator.start();

// make or inflate custom view for test purposes 
Button textView = new Button(this);
textView.setText("TestButton");
// add it to the frame layout that is the parent of the content on position 0
FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) content.getParent();
parent.addView(textView, 0);
```

The idea here is to use `ValueAnimator` that transforms and not just animates the main layout with the Action bar, so you can interact with the inflated view you want to use as a sliding panel. 
You should replace the hardcoded values with something that is of use to your app.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 6):

Well currently im working on a project and came across Sliding menu,i googled but gets very disappointed to see that no one has given some piece of code or some hint for how to start making a sliding menu,but every one has given link to some github's projects/libraries to use,I decided to do it myself and finally i have my own Sliding Menu Ready...

I have Spent two days on it

**1. on making animations of sliding**

**2. on making it work with all screen resolutions**

Its really easy and simple once you get some idea about **Animations**, i have read some where,its not sensible to re-invent the **Wheel**(people who are refering to github source code of sliding menu),but i beleif that you should atleast once try to make your own so you get a idea how it actually works and functions :P

so this is a picture of how my sliding menu will going to work

**1.Find.xml** `//later in the code it will be refer as findLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/find_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_header">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/filter_button" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Islamabad"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/city">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/interested_in"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Men and Women"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interested_in"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="18-24 years"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/separator_1" 
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/age"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text=">30km"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/users_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:numColumns="4">

    </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include 
        layout="@layout/filter"/> //here i included the filter.xml, which is on top of find.xml layout and is initially invisible    
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**2.Filter.xml** `//later in code refer as FilterLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_bg" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:background="@drawable/light_blue_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Raja Babar"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Male"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/seperator"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/separator_1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seperator"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="22 years"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_options" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/filter_options"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/interested_in_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_options"
        android:background="@drawable/interested_in_field">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/gender"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/women_men"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/age_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interested_in_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/age_field_1">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/age"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="18-24 years"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/distance_field">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/distance"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=">30km"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#33b9cd"/>


    </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

In **find.xml** i have included **filter.xml** initially which is invisible

Now **FilterAnimation.java**

```
package matchat.helpers;

import com.s3.matchat.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class FilterAnimation implements AnimationListener 
{
    Context context;

    RelativeLayout filterLayout, otherLayout;

    private Animation filterSlideIn, filterSlideOut, otherSlideIn, otherSlideOut;

    private static int otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight;

    private boolean isOtherSlideOut = false;

    private int deviceWidth;

    private int margin;

    public FilterAnimation(Context context) 
    {
        this.context = context;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // as my animation is x-axis related so i gets the device width and will use that width,so that this sliding menu will work fine in all screen resolutions
    }

    public void initializeFilterAnimations(RelativeLayout filterLayout)
    {
        this.filterLayout = filterLayout;

        filterSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_in);

        filterSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.filter_slide_out);    

    }

    public void initializeOtherAnimations(RelativeLayout otherLayout)
    {       
        this.otherLayout = otherLayout;

        otherLayoutWidth = otherLayout.getWidth();

        otherLayoutHeight = otherLayout.getHeight();


        otherSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_in);
        otherSlideIn.setAnimationListener(this);

        otherSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.other_slide_out);
        otherSlideOut.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public void toggleSliding()
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //check if findLayout is already slided out so get so animate it back to initial position
        {       
            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideIn);
        }
        else //slide findLayout Out and filterLayout In
        {
            otherLayout.startAnimation(otherSlideOut);

            filterLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            filterLayout.startAnimation(filterSlideIn);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        if(isOtherSlideOut) //Now here we will actually move our view to the new position,because animations just move the pixels not the view
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = false;
        }
        else
        {   
            margin = (deviceWidth * 80) / 100; //here im coverting device percentage width into pixels, in my other_slide_in.xml or other_slide_out.xml you can see that i have set the android:toXDelta="80%",so it means the layout will move to 80% of the device screen,to work across all screens i have converted percentage width into pixels and then used it



            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(otherLayoutWidth, otherLayoutHeight);

            params.leftMargin = margin;

            params.rightMargin = -margin; //same margin from right side (negavite) so that our layout won't get shrink

            otherLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            isOtherSlideOut = true;

            dimOtherLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
    {

    }

    private void dimOtherLayout()
    {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.5f);

        alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        otherLayout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    }

}
```

**Now Find.java**

```
package main.matchat.activities;

import matchat.helpers.FilterAnimation;
import com.s3.matchat.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Find extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    RelativeLayout filterLayout, findLayout;

    Button btFilter;

    FilterAnimation filterAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find);

        filterLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.filter_layout);

        findLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.find_layout);

        btFilter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.filter);
        btFilter.setOnClickListener(this);

        filterAnimation = new FilterAnimation(this);

        initializeAnimations(); 
    }

    private void initializeAnimations()
    {   //Setting GlobolLayoutListener,when layout is completely set this function will get called and we can have our layout onbject with correct width & height,else if you simply try to get width/height of your layout in onCreate it will return 0

        final ViewTreeObserver filterObserver = filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

        filterObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                filterLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

                int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                int filterLayoutWidth = (deviceWidth * 80) / 100; //here im coverting device percentage width into pixels, in my other_slide_in.xml or other_slide_out.xml you can see that i have set the android:toXDelta="80%",so it means the layout will move to 80% of the device screen,to work across all screens i have converted percentage width into pixels and then used it

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(filterLayoutWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                filterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);//here im setting the layout params for my filter.xml because its has width 260 dp,so work it across all screen i first make layout adjustments so that it work across all screens resolution 

                filterAnimation.initializeFilterAnimations(filterLayout);

            }
        });

        final ViewTreeObserver findObserver = findLayout.getViewTreeObserver();

        findObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                findLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                filterAnimation.initializeOtherAnimations(findLayout);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {

        case R.id.filter:

            filterAnimation.toggleSliding();

            break;
        }
    } 

}
```

Here are the animations res/anim

**1.filter_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true" />

</set>
```

**2.filter_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

**3.other_slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-80%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true"/>

</set>
```

**4.other_slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="80%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fillEnabled="true"/>

</set>
```

There you go a complete working and functional Sliding Menu, and you can customized it to meet your requirements,if any one still have some problems setting up,feel free to ask,i feel pleasure to help you out **:)**

Comment: While I am not a fan of [reinventing the wheel](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html), I appreciate the well-thought-out and complete answer that you provided here.

Comment: @hwrdprkns that was a joke...what i meant to say is that every one should adopt the behaviour of learn & implement :)

Comment: @hwrdprkns +1 for such a nice post on **reinventing the wheel**

Answer (score 5):

I've created my own solution for sliding away the view and revealing a menu underneath, as many other solutions appeared to not work on older Android versions or lacked proper instructions on how to get it to work.

My solution has the following features:

- Provides support for sliding away a view to reveal a menu that lies underneath it
- Both the menu and the view above can be any custom View
- Supported on old Android versions (tested to work at least on Android 2.2)
- Works with PhoneGap / Cordova projects

The solution uses a custom layout, called SlidingMenuLayout, that you are expected to add 2 views to. The first view you add is the menu, the second is the main view.

The simplest way to add the layout to your existing project is to override your Activity's `setContentView()` method:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    SlidingMenuLayout layout = new SlidingMenuLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        0.0F));
    layout.addView(new MenuView(this));
    layout.addView(view);
    super.setContentView(layout);
}
```

In this example, `MenuView` is the view that will actually show the menu. It is up to you to implement this view.
Finally, you can add a button (typically in the top left corner of your main view), that calls `openMenu()` or `closeMenu()` on the layout as appropriate.
The code for `SlidingMenuLayout` is found on the GitHub [project page](https://github.com/arendjr/SlidingMenuLayout/).

Comment: Hi, I liked your solution, I am working on 2.2 phone, it slides the "main" layout but it do show the "menu" layout as well even when i close the "menu". Any reason why?

Comment: I had the same issue, just make sure that the "main" layout has a background color and it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who uses the *SlidingMenu* library (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) there is a way to jack it in and it seems to work! With help of @Scirocco put this in your `onCreate` for the activity:

```
ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
mSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
ViewGroup mainContent = (ViewGroup) decorView.getChildAt(0);
decorView.removeView(mainContent);
mSlidingMenu.setContent(mainContent);
decorView.addView(mSlidingMenu);
mMenu = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.menuview, null);
mSlidingMenu.setMenu(mMenu);
mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
mSlidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
```

basically what it does is replacing the `linearlayout` in decor view with the `slidingmenu` instead.

Notice: Ive only tested it lightly but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout extends SlidingPaneLayout {
    Context context;
    FrameLayout left;
    FrameLayout right;
    Boolean canOpen = true;
    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.left = new FrameLayout(context);
        this.right = new FrameLayout(context);
        this.addView(left);
        this.addView(right);
    }
    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (canOpen)
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        else
            return false;
    }

    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout canOpen(Boolean canOpen) {
        this.canOpen = canOpen;
        return this;
    }

    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout makeActionBarSlide(Window window){
        ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) window.getDecorView();
        ViewGroup mainContent = (ViewGroup) decorView.getChildAt(0);
        decorView.removeView(mainContent);
        setContentView(mainContent);
        decorView.addView(this);
        return this;
    }

    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout setMenuView(View view){
        if((left.getChildCount()== 1)){
            left.removeView(left.getChildAt(0));
        }
        left.addView(view);
        return this;
    }

    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout setContentView(View view){
        if((right.getChildCount()== 1)){
            right.removeView(right.getChildAt(0));
        }
        right.addView(view);
        return this;
    }

    public ImprovedSlidingPaneLayout setMenuWidth(int width){
        left.setLayoutParams(new SlidingPaneLayout.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return this;
    }

}
```

this is my class extends `SlidingPaneLayout`. Can slide with actio

Comment: I've tried replacing the <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>  tag in layout xml with your class, but nothing is changed. Still sliding without the actionbar. Did you do any other thing and didn't mention here? Thanks!