# Google+ Style View/Fragment Animation?

Tags: android, animation, layout, google-plus

I've been looking for examples on how to animate two views (or fragments) left and right as is done in the [Android Google+ app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus). I have not been successful.

I would like to be able to slide in - left to right - a fragment over another one, at command, and as a reaction to the user swiping the screen. The animation should follow the user's finger across the screen, allowing them to pause in the middle of the animation etc.

Does anyone know where to start on this sort of layout animation? Tips on how Google+ does it? I'd like any information we can dig up! I've been quite unsuccessful =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best resource about the side menu, there is no code but a clear explanation on how to implement it:

[Fly-in app menu](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658)

and this is a post on how to animate the action bar related to the side menu:

[Slide action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Ah, if only I had searched for a fly in view! The tip about the action bar is also good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the effect by Simon based on Cyril Mottier's Fly-in app menu. - [Menu Drawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer)

Comment: I ended up using [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for my app.

Comment: watch out for a small arrow indicator for the item you have selected. In this project