# How can i create a sliding drawer with menu items?

Tags: android

How can I create a horizontal sliding drawer like the YouTube and Facebook app has.

[image]

Many other apps seem to use use the same style, so I'm guessing that this is a part of the default Androind UI framework but I can't seem to piece it together.

You can see some more samples [here](http://www.android-app-patterns.com//category/navigation).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did Google manage to do this? Slide ActionBar in Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a sliding menu, you can implement this by writing a custom view. There are a lot of good open source examples. I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) one.

You can use it by defining this in your Layout:

```
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    sliding:viewAbove="@layout/YOUR_ABOVE_VIEW"
    sliding:viewBehind="@layout/YOUR_BEHIND_BEHIND"
    sliding:touchModeAbove="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:touchModeBehind="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
    sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
    sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/YOUR_SCALE"
    sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SHADOW"
    sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/YOUR_SHADOW_WIDTH" />
```

### Edit:

The Android team introduced an official sliding pattern on Google IO 2013. Read everything about it [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Comment: I use this lib its good but sometime sliding drawer open very slowly

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it is not part of the default framework.  This is the only place I can find it mention in the Android docs http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html and I have search quite a bit.

This so far has been my favorite library https://bitbucket.org/verdigo/drawer/ straight forward and easy to use.

Also pretty recently HoloEverywhere library added a drawer you can use.  This one interests me since I use HoloEverywhere in most of my apps and it looks very similar to Foursquares.  https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 2):

```
How can I create a horizontal sliding drawer like the YouTube and Facebook app has.
```

FYI: These are not sliding drawer. That is [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). You can create a Navigation drawer by following [this sample project](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout).

Comment: User asked about `sliding action Bar` along with `content`. I cant find any way  to make it possible with Navigation Drawer