# Giving setting menu button in android application

Tags: android, menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a sliding drawer with menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027980/creating-a-sliding-drawer-with-menu-items)

As shown in the screen shot attached i need to show a menu in my application. How it is possible ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using action bar sherlock library,If so, first enable homebutton which is on left side of an actionbar

```
mActionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Then, Set Icon for that button

```
mActionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.image_name);
```