# PageTabStrip Class Not Found Exception

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-pageradapter

Well i have decided to just go with the pagertitlestrip. I am assuming that the support library that i am using does not contain pagertabstrip. i am not sure how to fix this because i thought i had everything updated correctly. 
Edit: Does this just not exist anymore? When i change the PagerTabStrip to a PagerTitleStrip everything works but i am unable to interact with the titles which is expected because that is why i wanted to use PagerTabStrip.

I have gone back to basics to find the root of my problem. I started a new project imported ABS. I setup a very simple pagerAdapter and a simple fragment. I used an example from a commons book and yet i am still getting the same error. Class Not Found Exception. Cannot find PagerTabStrip. Stack posted gets the same error every time. If i remove the PagerTabStrip then everything works correctly.

xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.pagetabswipe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
package com.example.pagetabswipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class SampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    Context ctxt=null;
    public SampleAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context ctxt) {
        super(fm);
        this.ctxt=ctxt;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return (EditorFragment.newInstance(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 10;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
    return(EditorFragment.getTitle(ctxt, position));
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
package com.example.pagetabswipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class EditorFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";

    static EditorFragment newInstance(int position) {
        EditorFragment frag = new EditorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return (frag);
    }

    static String getTitle(Context ctxt, int position) {
        return (String.format(ctxt.getString(R.string.hint), position + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);
        EditText editor = (EditText) result.findViewById(R.id.editor);
        int position = getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);
        editor.setHint(getTitle(getActivity(), position));
        return (result);
    }
}
```

Errors

```
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pagetabswipe/com.example.pagetabswipe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at com.example.pagetabswipe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     ... 11 more
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.pagetabswipe-2.apk]
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
11-24 18:01:25.630: E/AndroidRuntime(3505):     ... 20 more
```

Any help would be awesome. I am not sure where to look to fix this problem. I feel like i have missed something very basic that is preventing PagerTabStrip from being found in the support Library.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I'm currently with the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me, this ended up being due to the underlying actionbarsherlock library having an old version of the support library.

From eclipse, I removed android support library from the build path of the actionbarsherlock library project.

Then I followed the advice here, [PagerTabStrip cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756567/pagertabstrip-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type),

> Right Click on you project..
>
> click on "Android Tools" -> "Add Support Library"
>
> after that it will download the android-support.jar. and add it to your project.
>
> after that your eclipse will recognize PagerTabStrip

Comment: This sounds correct. I have not used eclipse in a long time but it would make sense that the support library in ABS was preventing me from using the correct support library. I did have this problem with other libraries as well and this was a good solution.