# How to solve slidingmenu+listview+viewpager touchEvent?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingmenu

I use slidingmenu in my app,and a fragement use viewpager in header of pulltoRefreshList, but I found I only can pull the list to refresh,but I can't slid the viewpager.

Comment: pls refer this : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and also this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application