# How to implement Slide ActionBar in Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

i want to design the ActionBar as it is in below figure ,
can any one help me out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11234375/2219600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to implement this. you can use Holoeverywhere library to achieve this based on your screenshot.

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 0):

everything we need to implement our slide transitions (created from the previous post), will happen in the onTabSelected() callback

create a public member in  calling activity which is instantiated to -1.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {              
      ...                
      //if moving to tab on the left, slide in from left  
      if(tab.getPosition() > mActivity.lastSelectedTab)  
      {  
           ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.tabsliderin, R.animator.tabsliderout);  
      }  
      // else slide in from right  
      else  
      {  
           ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.tabslidein_right, R.animator.tabslideout_right);  
      }              

      mActivity.lastSelectedTab = tab.getPosition();    
      ...  
 }
```