# Layout position is not updated in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

#### Expected Result

Like the Facebook app on Android, clicking on the toggle button on the upper left corner of the screen, it will show up the menu and slides out the content view rightward, thus give way to the left pane menu to show up. After the sliding animation gets finished, the content view's layout parameters gets updated to the final position on the right hand side so that the toggle button can respond to the clicking on the new position: the upper right corner. Then by giving a click on the right hand side toggle button now, the content view slide leftward and hide the left pane menu again.

#### Problem

After updating the final position of the content view, still the upper left corner could respond to the click event, not the upper right corner.

#### Source Code

**`Main.java > public class MainActivity extends Activity {}`**

```
public void onToggleButtonMenuClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean toggleTurnedOn = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
        
    if (toggleTurnedOn) { // If the toggle is turned on
        // Show menu
        LinearLayout mViewMenu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_menu);
        Animation animMenuOn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_menu_on);
        mViewMenu.startAnimation(animMenuOn);
            
        LinearLayout mViewContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_content);
        Animation animContentOff = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.anim_content_off);
        mViewContent.startAnimation(animContentOff);
            
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(480, 800);
        params.leftMargin = 384;  // Shift 384 pixels from left screen border
        params.rightMargin = -96; // Exceed 96 pixels from right screen border
        mViewContent.setLayoutParams(params); // This statement causes crash!
    } else {
          // Hide menu...
    } // End of toggle events handling
        
} // End of onToggleButtonMenuClicked()
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="329dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- The Menu View -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_menu"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_row_1_search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_search_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:hint="@string/edit_text_search_id"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_search_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="@string/button_search_id" />            
            
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <!-- Other rows in the menu are omitted -->

    </LinearLayout> <!-- End of Menu -->

    <!-- The Content View -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_content"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_button_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onToggleButtonMenuClicked" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_content"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_content" />

        </LinearLayout> <!-- End of Content -->

</FrameLayout> <!-- End of the root linear layout -->
```

Answer (score 0):

After learning something about [fillEnabled, fillBefore, and fillAfter](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html?showComment=1340781197891), I've figured out a work-around, something similar to [Muhammad Babar's work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880375/1939564).

**res > anim > anim_view_move_rightward.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="80%"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="false"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="0" />

</set>
```