# How to change the position of a linear layout within its parent frame layout in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-linearlayout

#### Expected Result

In `onClick()` callback method, programmatically set a new position for linear layout.

#### Problem

Neither the linear layout nor the button can be placed to a new place.

#### Source Code

`Main.java > public class MainActivity extends Activity {}`

Neither of the following two code snippet works.

(1)

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(480, 800); // unit is pixel
params.leftMargin = 420;  // Shift 420 pixels from left screen border
params.rightMargin = -60; // Exceed 60 pixels from right screen border
mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

(2)

```
Button mButtonMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_menu);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 55); // unit is pixel
params.leftMargin = 420; // unit is pixel
params.rightMargin = -60; // unit is pixel
mButtonMenu.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**`activity_main.xml` > elements structure**

```
<FrameLayout
    <ScrollView   <!-- The menu -->
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout <!-- The content -->
        <Button />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15880375/1939564 check Class FilterAnimation and method `onAnimationEnd()` for the movement of layouts

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thank you for your help, your link offers the solution, please move it to the answer part so that I can mark it as the solution for this post.

Comment: Pleased to heard that you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `LayoutParams` for the movement of your `LinearLayout`. Kindly refer the post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880375/1939564) check **Class** *FilterAnimation* and method `onAnimationEnd()` for the movement of layouts

Answer (score 1):

You can try swap LinearLayout with RelativeLayout.

And then when you want to make some view to be under/above another you can use this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);                            

YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you @dasdasd, but what I need here is to moving (or _tranlating_) the linear layout horizontally to another place. Any idea about that?

Comment: what do you mean another place? you want to make it in another layout?
I think that using RelativeLayout is the easy way.

Comment: Alright, let me explain it: in the beginning the content view (a linear layout) is on top of the slide menu (a scroll view), both of these two are in a frame layout so that the overlapped layout can be placed there. Then clicking on the upper left corner of the content view, the content view slides rightward and show the hidden menu behind.