# Samsung Galaxy S2 Screen blinking with my App

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am beginner of Android Developer.I just published a app on google and I get some of feedback which is screen keep on blinking in Samsung Galaxy S2.  But I tested it with Nexus4 and Samsung galaxy S3 with no such problem at all. and also tested it with simulator Android 2.3.3(API 10)also No problem with it.

Since I do not own a Galaxy S2 device, do you guys have any idea which part I should look for in order to find out the problem? because I really no idea, Please help and give advice. thanks.

the app implemented some of external library which is:
(jfeinstein10) - SlidingMenu and (chrisbanes) -Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: if you don't mind giving the link to the app i can try it on my s2

Comment: you need to have a real device test [here](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action) this service is provided by Samsung it self

Comment: hmm i think the *blink* effect is due to the `Translate Animation`!! you can try `setFillEnabled(true)` in animation and also try to reduce the time of animation, i have implemented my own sliding menu you can check it out http://stackoverflow.com/a/15880375/1939564

Comment: lelloman - can i have your email? so i can send u thru. there is some reason i cant leave it here directly. hope u can understand.
user1283633 - i will try to get 1 from my friend, thanks for advice.
Muhammad Babar - thanks for your advice, but the problem i get from feedback so far is only appear in Galaxy S2. did u experienced on it before? i will try to set the attribute u mentioned, hopefully it is. thanks

Comment: Did you got any solution for the blinking issue??? @NaiveBz