# Actionbar and Navigation drawer - slide Actionbar with Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, drawer

I am using a Navigation Drawer as shown [here: Android Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0lCs.png). At the moment, the Actionbar is static, it does not move when the Drawer opens/closes (only it's title changes). How can I apply this effect:

[image]

I want the entire ActionBar to move with the Sliding fragment. And the Name and Buttons on the ActionBar to remain as they are. Please tell me what code you would need to see.

**ALSO, Question 2:**

When you're using `DrawerLayout` you include in the xml the FrameLayout (for the content_frame) and ListView (where you add your navigation settings... In that Drawer, can you modify the layout so that you can add not just ListView but other Views aswell? On top or bottom of the ListView? Something like this:

[image]

I want to add ImageView (not hyperlinked, just Image) and Additional TextViews (for instructions) not hyperlinked.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application)

Comment: I will add that to my code. Please also see Question 2 on my Edit above.

Comment: @KickAss: if possible,plz post customised code of `NavigationDrawer`, It will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: Customised how? I now use ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu libraries. These both are backward compatible and very easy to implement and customise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using `SlidingMenu` library from `GitHub`. It's powerfull flexible and also you can do ANYTHING with it. You can slide the actionbar by just simply calling:

```
setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
```

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Wow if I knew of this 2 days ago, I would not have spent 2 days trying to make the Android Example work and customizing it :(

Comment: after download this code..this code contains error. Please solve it. I got frustrated.

Comment: actually there need abs library. what is that ? please solve it. please please

Comment: I tried to use the sliding menu. But when slider opens the main view is not getting faded like other apps has.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal Make sure to add these lines :
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);

Comment: But that is for Sliding Menu shadow. I am talking about the main screen content that has to fade when slider menu opens.

Comment: @omarfarhat97 very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To the second point: Sure you can. The NavigationDrawer is not limited to use just the ListView. Just use a ViewGroup like a LinearLayout as the 2nd child of the DrawerLayout and put in any View you want.
But keep in mind to add this line in the specification of your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
     ...
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     ...>

     <TextView..../>
     <ImageView...../>
<LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. This is the code from sample source code of the example you are refering.

```
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this kind of layout to implement the some view on the top of the drawer list view..

```
<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#191919" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_Search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FC3A3B"
        android:hint="  Search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit_Search"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_small_search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_Search"
        android:background="#191919"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```