# Implement navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i was able to implement navigation drawer like this.its navigate on the my MainActivity.

[image]

but can i navigate my drawer like this app?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Have a look at this:

[slide actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234375/how-did-google-manage-to-do-this-slide-actionbar-in-android-application)

or

2) Consider using [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) from GitHub . It's powerfull flexible and also you can do ANYTHING with it. You can slide the actionbar by just simply calling:

```
setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android v4 widget Navigation Drawer doesn't move your Actionbar and your content. If you want to move the whole content to right with the slider then use this [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). It provides the exact what you are looking for.